# how to verify the sorting in collapse group selenium web driver-java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i want to test the sorting in collapse group?? it's possible or not? Please share that how to do it. blow pic have two group 1) Branch:Clifton and 2) Branch: Holsopple.(columns are sorted by clicking on Columns heading(Contact, Type etc)).below mentioned code work where group is not exist but fail where is group on page.

when i compare the gettext in java it shows result false while sorting of the text on the page is correct,because my java code gets the text in whole column and sorting is on collapse group. I wanna write the code which verify the sorting of columns on collapse group base.

HTML is here:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="rgGroupHeader">
<td class="rgGroupCol">
<td colspan="9">
<p>Branch: Clifton</p>
</td>
</tr>
<td class="rgGroupCol"/>
<td style="display:none;" title="289855">289855</td>
<td style="display:none;" title="31">31</td>
<td style="display:none;"/>
<td style="display:none;" title="12">12</td>
<td style="display:none;" title="6">6</td>
<td class="col_priority">
<td title="10/24/2013">10/24/2013</td>
<td class="col_status">
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl19_divStatus" class="status_active" title="Open - Active"/>
</td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td title="Nawaz, S (10/22/2013)">
<td class="col_manager_instruction">
<td class="col_expiry" title="N/A">N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00__8" class="rgRow">
<td class="rgGroupCol"/>
<td style="display:none;" title="289856">289856</td>
<td style="display:none;" title="31">31</td>
<td style="display:none;"/>
<td style="display:none;" title="11">11</td>
<td style="display:none;" title="6">6</td>
<td class="col_priority">
<td title="10/24/2013">10/24/2013</td>
<td class="col_status">
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td title="Nawaz, S (10/22/2013)">
<td class="col_manager_instruction">
<td class="col_expiry" title="11/25/2013">11/25/2013</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rgGroupHeader">
<td class="rgGroupCol">
<input id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00__35__0" class="rgCollapse" type="button" title="Collapse group" onclick="$find("ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00")._toggleGroupsExpand(this, event); return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$CPHPageContents$dtgLeads$ctl00$ctl37$ctl00','')" value=" " name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$dtgLeads$ctl00$ctl37$ctl00"/>
</td>
<td colspan="9">
<p>Branch: Holsopple</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00__16" class="rgRow">
<td class="rgGroupCol"/>
<td style="display:none;" title="289768">289768</td>
<td style="display:none;" title="2">2</td>
<td style="display:none;"/>
<td style="display:none;" title="12">12</td>
<td style="display:none;" title="4">4</td>
<td class="col_priority">
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_divPriority" class="priority_high" title="High"/>
</td>
<td title="06/27/2013">06/27/2013</td>
<td class="col_status">
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_divStatus" class="status_active" title="Open - Active"/>
</td>
<td>
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_divInner">
<a id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_hlnkContact" href="/Leads/Research/289768">John Ross</a>
<input id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_hdfContactID" type="hidden" value="174120" name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$dtgLeads$ctl00$ctl38$hdfContactID"/>
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_divContactCardControl" class="pos_r"/>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="lead_type">
<a id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_lnkType" class="lead_type_link" href="/Leads/Research/289768" title="Maturing CD 100">Maturing CD 100</a>
<a id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_lnkDownArrow" class="down_arrow" onclick="showCloseTransferLayer('ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_CloseTransferLayer')" href="javascript:;"/>
<span class="pos_r">
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_CloseTransferLayer">
<a id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_lnkCloseLead" onclick="return ShowPopupForm('/Forms/Popups/CloseLead.aspx?LeadID=289768','WindowCloseLead');" href="javascript:;">Cancel Lead</a>
<a id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_lnkTransferLead" onclick="return ShowPopupForm('/Forms/Popups/TransferLead.aspx?LeadID=289768','WindowTransferLead');" href="javascript:;">Transfer Lead</a>
</div>
</span>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_divAssignedTo">
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_ddlAssignedTo" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default assigned_to_combo" style="width:160px;">
<table style="border-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;" summary="combobox">
<tbody>
<tr class="rcbReadOnly">
<td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
<input id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_ddlAssignedTo_Input" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Org, T" name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$dtgLeads$ctl00$ctl38$ddlAssignedTo" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>
<td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
<a id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_ddlAssignedTo_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;">
<div id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_ddlAssignedTo_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="display:none;">
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;">
<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
<li class="rcbItem">Ghaffar, A</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Keller, K</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Nawaz, S</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Org, 1</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Org, T</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_ddlAssignedTo_ClientState" type="hidden" name="ctl00_CPHPageContents_dtgLeads_ctl00_ctl38_ddlAssignedTo_ClientState" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td/>
<td class="col_manager_instruction">
<td class="col_expiry" title="N/A">N/A</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

[image: Image is attached for more description]

Java Code:

```
List<String> displayedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> SortedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        String getData;

        Thread.sleep(thread);

        for(int i=0;i<tableType.size();i++)
        {

            getData=tableType.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(getData);
            displayedNames.add(getData);
            SortedNames.add(getData);


        }
        System.out.println(displayedNames);

        Thread.sleep(thread);

        List<String> sortingOperation = displayedNames;

        Thread.sleep(thread);

        Collections.sort(sortingOperation);

        Thread.sleep(thread);

        Assert.assertEquals(SortedNames, sortingOperation);
```

Comment: Can you update the question with html source ?

Comment: i have posted the HtML in above query please review.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<String> displayedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> SortedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
 Thread.sleep(10000);
 WebElementtableType=action.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='table_1_core_table_content']/tbody/tr"));
Thread.sleep(10000);
List<WebElement>rowElmt=tableType.findElements(By.xpath("//tr/td[5]"));
String getData;
Thread.sleep(5000);
for(int i=2;i<rowElmt.size();i++)
{

    getData=rowElmt.get(i).getText();
    displayedNames.add(getData);
    SortedNames.add(getData);


}

 System.out.println(displayedNames);
Thread.sleep(5000);
List<String> sortingOperation = displayedNames;
Collections.sort(sortingOperation);
Assert.assertEquals(SortedNames, sortingOperation);
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow you would probably be better editing your comments into your answer. For clarity a couple of sentences about your changes may also help.